# Twitter API - Get a user's hashtags

Tags: twitter

Is it possible to use the Twitter API to get a list of all hashtags the user has ever used in their tweets?

For example, with the result:

```
["#LikeOMG", "#NeedToKnow", "#hashtag"  ... ]
```

Comment: This should be implemented....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not directly, no.  The easiest thing to do is download a [User's Timeline](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/user_timeline).

Note:

> This method can only return up to 3,200 of a user’s most recent Tweets

In each Tweet, you will be able to extract the hashtag from the `entities` field.  From there, depending on which programming language you're using, you can create a unique array.